# Javascript curl equivalent

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application up and running, with actuator endpoints configured mainly the `/shutdown` endpoint. I've been shutting it down (previously) with `^C` and now am shutting down with `curl -XPOST https://address:port/shutdown`. My question is how would I map a command like that to a javascript function so I can shutdown the application with the click of a button?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to execute curl command using javascript function so better use AJAX.

See below threads.

[Executing curl from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804639/executing-curl-from-javascript)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31179836/6572971

Otherwise you can use java code to make it shutdown like below.

[Programmatically shut down Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944144/programmatically-shut-down-spring-boot-application)

Answer (score 2):

By using Fetch ?

```
const myPost = async (postBody) => {
  const rawResponse = await fetch('https://address:port/shutdown', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(postBody)
  });
  const response = await rawResponse.json();
  console.log(response);
);
```